# Validation with two for loops in servlet not working

Tags: java, validation, for-loop, servlets

I am working on a booking application and I want to validate two things. First I want to check if a booking already exists and secondly I want to check if the id number that is entered exists in my database. The problem is that I can't make the two for loops work together.

This is how my code loooks now:

```
else if(operation.equals("book")){
    String sessionnr = request.getParameter("dropdown");
    String pnr = request.getParameter("pnr");
    url = "/Book.jsp";

    if(pnr !=null && sessionnr !=null){
        boolean p = false;

        for(Booking b: facade.getBookings()){
            if(b.getId().getSessionnr().equals(sessionnr) && b.getId().getPnr().equals(pnr)){
                feedback = "This booking already exists!";
                request.setAttribute("feedback", feedback);
                p=true;
            }
        }
        for(Customer c: facade.getAllCustomers()){
            if(!c.getPnr().equals(pnr)){
                feedback = "Id no exist";
                request.setAttribute("feedback", feedback);
                p=true;
            }
        }


            if(p!=true){
            facade.createBooking(pnr, sessionnr);
            feedback="You have made a booking!";
            request.setAttribute("feedback", feedback);
            }

            ArrayList <Session> list4 = facade.getAllSessions();
            request.setAttribute("sessions", list4);
            url = "/Book.jsp";
    }

        }

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Why isn't this working? Is there any way to do it without using two for loops?

Comment: Add 'break' for exiting from loop into if condition

Comment: And if 'p == true' your all attribes will be changed because you adding new attributes from ArrayList.

Comment: I am trying to use 'break' but not sure how it should look.... Should i use it in both for loops?